# How to integrate augmented-reality into monaca/cordova

Tags: cordova, augmented-reality, vuforia, monaca, aurasma

I am familliar with augmented-reality system like vuforia/aurasma.

and had experiences in making native applications with these SDK.

however now I need to integrate this augmented-reality function to the exist application which are made by monaca.

I am not familiar with monaca, so googling around for searching some pluging for monaca but in vain.

Does anyone have the good suggestion for solving this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how fare you're inside AR and how much money you can "use" for that but nearly the best AR plugin for Hybrid-Applications comes from [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/).

It has a large Documentation for iOS -> [iOS Documentation Wikitude](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/ios) and also already an existing and working plugin for cordova/phonegap with also a very large documentation. [Cordova/Phonegap Wikitude Docs](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap)

We're working with that software since a few month and it is working so fine that we don't want anything else. Have a look at it, it works like a charme in my mind! :)

Comment: thanks it is the great suggetion!! I am also interested in wikitude as well. It's really easy to integrate.

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, as far as i know it is the best solution and it works perfectly fine!

Comment: Does wikitude support IKEA like application in which can interact with 3d object like placing and resizing ?